# A better way to visualize catch data

Tags: r, ggplot2

not sure if this is outside the scope of Stack Overflow.  Let me know if it is.

My input [data](http://pastebin.com/2qFvVaXB).

I am trying to visualize (or perform some as yet to be determined analysis) the size distribution of individuals caught during 468 different capture sessions.  The capture sessions are labelled as "id", and I made a new column "newID" which numbered the sessions from 1:468 for simplicity (I made a nice loop to make this new column if anyone is interested in the code).  The sizes I am plotting are in the column "SL".

I also have columns designating the "Date," "Year," "Month," "Location," and "Creek" the given capture session occurred during. The data could definitely be split up into smaller segments (for example, there are 4 creeks, so I could do a separate plot for each creek), but I don't want to go down that road unless that is my only option.

So far I have done a simple preliminary plot facetted by "Year" (just for simplicity so the data doesn't stack too closely) with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
CreekDat <-read.table("CreekData.txt",header=TRUE)
CreekData4<-data.frame(CreekDat)

DOT <-ggplot(CreekData4,aes(newID,SL,color=factor(newID)))
DOT<-DOT+facet_grid(Year~.)
DOT<-DOT+stat_boxplot(aes(x = newID,y=SL))
DOT
```

And got this result http://ufsnook.smugmug.com/photos/i-psJZ6kw/0/X3/i-psJZ6kw-X3.jpg

Having ~500 events I want to show a size distribution for is a bit much... I was wondering if anyone knew of any other plotting options that may work for this data, had any advice for working within the boxplots I am currently using, or have any ideas for non-visual analyses I could look at.

Comment: why not try a tile plot; x is time, y is size, color is count, and facet by creek? I might plot this when I have time...

Comment: By 'time' do you mean 'date' or the 'newID'.  There can be multiple 'IDs' per 'date' (we sometimes have up to 15 capture sessions in a given day), and the individual capture sessions are much more important for my purposes than the individual dates.  I might like where this is going though... So for color we would do the count (ie. # of individuals caught in a given session/ID)?  Any suggestions on how to do that part?

Comment: Do you have the time of the capture sessions? If you could add those it would help you see that dimension. I think we'll have to bin SL, which can be done arbitrarily. Give me an hour or two...

Comment: I have incomplete time data, and when I tried to append it from the "12:00" format to the CreekData within R it converted what data I had to "integer".  I can make up some times and append them manually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a fun one. I ended up binning the data and aggregating.

```
require(ggplot2)

# read the file into a data frame
CreekData <-read.table("CreekData.txt",header=TRUE)

# fix the date
CreekData$Date <- as.POSIXct(paste(CreekData$Year,
                                   CreekData$Month,
                                   "1 12:00",
                                   sep = "-"),
                             format = "%y-%m-%d %H:%M",
                             tz = "GMT")
# bin the size
CreekData$SL.binned <- cut(CreekData$SL,
                           breaks = c(seq(0,500,50),1000),
                           labels = c(paste(seq(0,450,50),
                                            "-",
                                            seq(50,500,50)),
                                      ">500"),
                           right = FALSE,
                           ordered_result = TRUE)
# add something we can sum!
CreekData$SL.bin.count <- rep(1,length(CreekData$SL.binned))

# aggregate it
CreekDataAg <- aggregate(x = CreekData$SL.bin.count,
                         by = list("Date" = CreekData$Date,
                                   "Location" = CreekData$Location,
                                   "SL.binned" = CreekData$SL.binned),
                         FUN = sum)
names(CreekDataAg)[4] <- "Count"

# plot it
p <- ggplot(data = CreekDataAg,
            aes(x = Date,
                y = SL.binned)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Count,
                color = Count),
            size = 0) +
  facet_wrap(~Location) +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "Count",
                      low = "grey50",
                      high = "steelblue") +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "grey50",
                       high = "steelblue") +
  scale_y_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
  labs(title = expression(atop("Count by size interval",
                               atop(italic("something else")))),
       x = "Date",
       y = "Size range") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 8, base_family = "")
print(p)
```

You then end up with a plot that looks like this:

[image]

It needs some work to fix the colors in the plot, but that shouldn't be too hard.

You can also bin by ID, replacing the `Date` in the agrgegation and plotting with `newID`. That gets you...

[image]

Comment: Very cool.  One thing that I am not sure if I am following.  Are you combining all of the data within a given day?  In other words, if we have 5 capture events (different ID's) in a given day, are those all collapsed to one x-axis point here?

Comment: I am aggregating all of the capture events by day, because I didn't have the hour data. If you wanted to, you could replace the `Date` in the aggregation and plotting with the newID. I've added an example of this.

Comment: One question on this.  For a single ID in the 2nd plot, is it varying the fill&color to denote the number of individuals in each size bin that were captured on that sample?  I think it is, but I'm not 100% certain

Comment: In the second plot, each ID and size range at each location has a count; let's call this combination of ID, size range a tile. The color of the tiles varies with the count. The same color scale is used for all plots, but that can be changed. If you want to make it a bit clearer, you could do the aggregation and plotting by Creek rather than location, maybe?

Comment: Thanks Lost Brit, made some alterations to produce the following plots  [1](http://ufsnook.smugmug.com/photos/i-GkN7DXC/0/X3/i-GkN7DXC-X3.jpg)
[2](http://ufsnook.smugmug.com/photos/i-xGvnx3t/0/X3/i-xGvnx3t-X3.jpg)
[3](http://ufsnook.smugmug.com/photos/i-bLqDvJK/0/X3/i-bLqDvJK-X3.jpg)
[4](http://ufsnook.smugmug.com/photos/i-4DQFnXC/0/X3/i-4DQFnXC-X3.jpg)